# Is there any equivalent syntax for C# Type.GetType() in java

Tags: java

Please let me know Is there any equivalent syntax for C# `Type.GetType()` in java.

And equivalent syntax of `Activator.CreateInstance()` in java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

***Type.GetType() equivalent***

Use [Object.getClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) or `instanceof`

***Activator.CreateInstance() equivalent***

If a class has a no-argument constructor, then creating an object from its package-qualified class name is usually done using using [Class.forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) and [Class.newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) like below

```
 Class clazz = Class.forName("test.Demo");
 Demo demo = (Demo) clazz.newInstance();
```

If class dosent have no-argument constructor you must use Reflection like below

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
Object object = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { ctorArgument });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might achieve something like using Java reflection

```
Class c - object.getClass();

object.getClass().getConstructors()[0].newInstance(initargs);
```